# What exceptions in asp.net 5 could/should be considered as "permanent" vs. "non permanent"?

Tags: .net-5, cqrs, event-sourcing

If an Eventhandler that updates a projection in the read model throws an exception, this is a bad thing.

In this case I would like do differentiate between "permanent" and "non permanent" exceptions.
With "permanent" Exceptions I mean Exceptions, that most likely are caused by wrong code and will be thrown again and again if I try to retry handling the event on this event handler.
With "non permanent" Exceptions I mean "temporary" e.g. Io/Network/... related Exceptions that are not caused by wrong code and which make sense to retry until the event is eventually handled successfully.

While I can come up with examples I would consider the one or the other (like InvalidOperation or IOException) is there any list or recommendation which exception (in this case in the asp.net 5 stack) should be considered what?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a retry or circuit breaker policy using [Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/) that automatically retries all the exceptions (per read-model) and after X retries, do either disable the specific read projection that failed or the entire read-model.

The question is what you want to happen when the read model can't be updated. Do you:

- Shut down the specific projection and allow the rest to be updated?
- Shut down the entire read model
- Or enter a "I am out of sync" mode?

I think this all depends on how you have constructed your read model and what your business case is.